# WebApi2 - UrlEncoded uri as uri segment / controller action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a need to pass a uri as a route param to a webapi action method:

`http://some.url/api/controller/method/%2FforeignRoute%2F7e12cd15-d49d-4b16-9fe5-94b5f3ea3ecd%2Fhello%2Fworld%2FsomeResourceId`

.. which would map to an attribute route definition:

`Route("api/controller/method/{theuri}")`

.. but the final segment is always being decoded and asp.net/webapi returns a 404.

This doesn't feel like it should be an issue, but perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

The URL Encoded value of `%2F` is the Forward Slash `/` and thus your uri becomes

```
http://some.url/api/controller/method//foreignRoute/7e12cd15-d49d-4b16-9fe5-94b5f3ea3ecd/hello/world/someResourceId
                                     ^^
```

double slash is creating the problem here. which is not available and you get the 404. You should change it to

```
Route("api/controller/method{theuri}")
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue, that would've been a typo. also, the parameter should not be getting unencoded, or in any event, webapi should be seeing everything after `/method/` as `{theuri}` regardless of whether or not it is encoded or not. At least, that's the desire.